# Defining a string using a variable, then using that variable as an imput

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to this site, so please bear with me. I need to create a rock paper scissors program that outputs each round and the winner of each round, but am having difficulties with the inputs. When I run my program (this is only a section of it), the computer is able to recognize that R=rock, P=paper, and S=scissors, however when R, P, or S is input in PlayerChoice, the program does not understand that R stands for rock or P stands for Paper, etc.  How can I fix this problem?

```
R='rock'
P='paper'
S='scissors'
RPS=[R,P,S]
Name=input('please enter your name')

while PlayerCounter<3 and CompCounter<3

PlayerChoice=input('choose:rock(R),paper(P),scissors(S)')

CompChoice=RPS[random.randint(0,2)]

print('computer chose ' + str(CompChoice))
```

this is a sample of the output

```
__________Game  1 __________
choose:rock(R),paper(P),scissors(S) R
computer chose rock
__________Game  1 __________
choose:rock(R),paper(P),scissors(S)P
computer chose rock
__________Game  1 __________
choose:rock(R),paper(P),scissors(S)S
computer chose scissors
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO is for asking specific questions about specific problems, not a code writing service; please review [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should look into *dictionaries*.

Comment: What is your problem here??? Just write a line of code before this line `CompChoice=RPS[random.randint(0,2)]`, write `print "player Choice:"+PlayerChoice` see what you want then.

Comment: I guess the conceptual problem is the following: `input` will give you a string ('R', 'P' or 'S' if entered correctly). Now python does not know (a priori) that this string is also the name of one of your objects (R,P and S). Getting around this problem can be done in various ways, the most simple IMHO is with dictionaries, that allow to link a value to a key. See my other comment for how this could work.

Comment: Try `choices = {'R': 'rock', 'P': 'paper', 'S': 'scissors'}` then write `PlayerChoice=choices[input('choose...')]`. If this works for you, congrats, you just used a python dictionary! The other might then write `CompChoice=random.choice(choices.values())`

Answer (score 1):

"Understand" is a matter of programming.  You have to use the same representation for both players.  The problem here is that you used the characters 'R', 'P', 'S' for the player, but integers 0, 1, 2 for the computer.  Try this:

```
move_dict = {'R': 0, 'P': 1, 'S': 2}
player_num = move_dict[PlayerChoice]
move_diff = CompChoice - player_num
# Now you evaluate move_diff to find out who wins.
```

I recommend that you convert the player choice to the same integers set.  Then you can simply subtract the two choices to find out who won: 0 is a tie, 1 or -2 is one side; 2 or -1 is the other side.  You can use the modulus operation "% 3" to map that to just 0, 1, 2 as a game result.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: FYI: For the computer he does not use integers: `RPS[random.randint(0,2)]` will result in a string.

Comment: I know; he needs to change that.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to use a single list to handle the moves of the player and the computer in this case. The transition from the strings to characters is an unnecessary complication.

```
import random

# Establish the potential values from which players can choose
values = ["R", "P", "S"]

chosen = 0
# Don't proceed until the user has provided reasonable input
while chosen == 0:
    # The [0] at the end of this finds the first letter, even if the player inputs something like "rock"
    player_choice = input("Choose rock (R), paper (P), or scissors (S): ").upper()[0]
    if player_choice in values:
        chosen = 1 # Allow the program to proceed

# Choose a random value for the computer
computer_choice = values[random.randint(0, 2)]

# Display the results
print("The computer chose \"" + computer_choice + "\" and the player chose \"" + player_choice + "\"")
```

However, I agree with Prune's response: you should use integers in place of characters or strings, else you'll have some complicated logic to determine the winner of the game (paper beats rock, rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper, rock is beaten by paper, scissors are beaten by rock, paper is beaten by scissors).